# Cannot find module 'D:\..\server\node_modules\sequelize\types\utils'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I am coding a React app in VS code and I had run it multiple times, everything was working great, and when I ran npm start another time, the server crashed and gave me this error. I hadn't changed anything in my code, one minute it was working and then the other not. I've tried deleting node modules, package-lock.json, but nothing works. Does anyone have any idea? I didn't know what snippets of code, if any, I should include, so please tell me.

This is the full error that I get

Error: Cannot find module 'D:..\server\node_modules\sequelize\types\utils'
at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:15)
at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:953:15)
at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:14)
at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (D:\LanguageCentre\server\routes\Users.js:7:23)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
path: 'D:\..\server\node_modules\sequelize\package.json'

Comment: did you `require("sequelize/types");` in any file

Comment: @DreamyPlayer No, I didn't

Comment: check again all fies for `sequelize/types`

Comment: Besides my models, there is not one occurrence of the word 'types' in my server folder. And this is what a model looks like: module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Comments = sequelize.define("Comments", {
        commentBody: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    });
    return Comments;
};